# Create Behavior from Map Property in Control - Xamarin Forms MVVM Prism ArcGIS

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, prism, arcgis, esri

I'm trying to show a callout when navigating from View A (form view) to View B (map view). I pass the record detail for the callout from View A to View B and it's bound to viewmodel of View B.

I would like to access the LoadStatusChanged event on the Map property of the Esri MapView control while adhering to MVVM architecture. Here is what my control looks like:

```
        <esri:MapView x:Name="mapViewMain"
                  Map="{Binding MainMap}"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  InteractionOptions="{Binding MapViewOptions}"
                  GraphicsOverlays="{Binding GraphicsOverlays}">
        <esri:MapView.Behaviors>
            <bh:ShowCalloutOnTapBehavior CalloutClickCommand="{Binding GoToDetailCommand}" />
            <bh:ShowCalloutOnDataReceivedBehavior MeterMasterRequest="{Binding RequestParameters}" Map="{Binding MainMap}" />
        </esri:MapView.Behaviors>
    </esri:MapView>
```

I think I need to create a behavior that will take in the Map, wait for it to finish load, then show callout (results of MeterMasterRequest) on MapView (the ShowCallout method is on MapView control).

```
    public class ShowCalloutOnDataReceivedBehavior : BehaviorBase<MapView>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MeterMasterRequestProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MeterMasterRequest), typeof(MeterMasterRequest), typeof(ShowCalloutOnDataReceivedBehavior));

    public static readonly BindableProperty MapProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Map), typeof(Map), typeof(ShowCalloutOnDataReceivedBehavior));

    public MeterMasterRequest MeterMasterRequest
    {
        get { return (MeterMasterRequest)GetValue(MeterMasterRequestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MeterMasterRequestProperty, value); }
    }

    public Map Map
    {
        get { return (Map)GetValue(MapProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapProperty, value); }
    }
```

How can I bind to the Map event from here? I don't know how I can get BehaviorBase to be of type Map. I seem to only be able to set behaviors at MapView level.

Comment: Why can't you just subscribe to the Map's LoadStatusChanged event in your view model? You can do it whenever the Map property is set. Just make sure to unsubscribe from the event on the old Map that is being replaced if there was a previous Map whose LoadStatusChanged event you subscribed to as well. Not unsubscribing can cause a memory leak.

Comment: Could you kindly point me to an example? I thought it goes against MVVM to call event from VM, that's why I was trying to figure out how to get reference to map in a behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I thought the code above was your view model. What I meant is that you could subscribe to that event in the property setter for Map property when a new map is assigned to the property.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Map` from the `MapView.Map` property and the `MapView` is  passed in to the `OnAttachedTo` and `OnDetachingFrom` methods of the `Behavior` class. I see you have a `BehaviorBase`, which hopefully has the `OnAttachedTo` and `OnDetachingFrom` overrides still marked as `protected virtual` so you can override them in your `ShowCalloutOnDataReceivedBehavior` class

Override the `OnAttachedTo` method and then subscribe to the `LoadStatusChanged` event, override `OnDetachingFrom` so you can unsubscribe like so:

```
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(MapView bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.Map.LoadStatusChanged += Map_LoadStatusChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(MapView bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.Map.LoadStatusChanged -= Map_LoadStatusChanged;
    }

    private void Map_LoadStatusChanged(object sender, Esri.ArcGISRuntime.LoadStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff when LoadStatusChanged event is fired on the Map
    }
```

Comment: Mahaloz for the replies, but I did try that but Map is coming back as null. I think because the behavior gets loaded before the view model. I set Map in the constructor of my view model.

Comment: Yah, sorry, OnAttached runs before the XAML is finished loading. Not sure of the best way to deal with that right now.